# Update form, based on previous values

Tags: angular, typescript

User fills in a form. When submitting it, they will be forwarded to a register page. Once they are signed in, they will be forwarded to the form page. However, I don't want them to fill the same form again. Instead, once the form is submitted, I store the values in localStorage:

```js
if (this.id) {
  localStorage.setItem(this.id.toString(), JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
  this._router.navigate(['register']).then(r => r);
}
```

This is how I try to update the form values:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if (this.id) {
    const formValues = localStorage.getItem(this.id.toString());
    if (formValues) {
      const storedFormValue = JSON.parse(formValues);
      console.log(storedFormValue); // <-- Data is correct
      if (storedFormValue) {
        this.form.patchValue(storedFormValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't seen any changes and there is no error.

Comment: Please share relevant code where you assign `this.form` and show the template where you bind to the FormGroup.

Comment: can u please explain your que.  I dont get it